# Magento 1.9 Which database is getQuote()->getGrandTotal() used?

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, grand-total

I have this code in a custom module

```
Mage::getSingleton("checkout/cart")->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()
```

Which table and which column does this code getting data from?

First I thought it was the field **grand_total** from **sales_flat_quote**, but it's not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this code below table used

```
sales_flat_quote
```

and Feild used is of this table

```
grand_total
```

Edit

If you look at this file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
```

then this is the same table is used for `sales/quote`

Check this way

```
 Mage::getSingleton("checkout/cart")->getQuote()->getId();
```

and check grand_total at that Id

Comment: I also think it's the grand_total. but when I manually updated the grand_total to 0, the code still getting me some numbers. that's I'm confused if it is the grand_total that is used. how come it's not getting the number I manually wrote in the DB. And I'm sure it is the correct entity_id I edited with.

Comment: @xxx What is your requirement

Comment: A custom module that I'm working on, is calculating the amount wrong when Gift Voucher applied. If it's 100% discount, it doesnt remove the tax from shipping cost. so the total amount customer need to pay is the tax of the shipping cost, which the amount should be 0 since it's a 100% giftcard. I end up with the code above, and try to modify the grand_total to 0 if it's 100% giftcard. it it's now working. that's why Im confused.

Comment: @xxx `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Tax.php` debug this class

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this code will get grand_total updated?  Mage::getSingleton("checkout/cart")->getQuote()->setGrandTotal(0)->save();

Comment: @xxx this will update the quote but need to check if magento chabge value after your code or not

Comment: you are right, Magento does change the value back after I updated the field. I think Magento change the value back every time I refresh the shopping cart page.  where in the code does Magento update the value? I think it's that part I need to work with. Thanks.

Comment: @xxx  `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Grand.php`  collect method change setGrandTotal